# get data-id attribute from dynamically created divs

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension that needs to get the `data-id` attribute of all of the songs listed [here](https://music.twitter.com/i/chart/pop). The problem I'm having is that the html seems to be made dynamically after it is sent to my browser, which makes the attribute harder to access.

What is a way that I could make an array of all of the `data-id`s of the songs on that page? It is also important that I accomplish this without stopping the page from displaying as it normally does (another issue I'm facing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tell us that it is harder because the content is dynamicly loaded. Which tells me that you perform a AJAX request from within your extension.

instead of reloading the HTML of the webpage into a variable. Just use the dom of the webppage. You should build a backgroundpage, and use `executeScript`

Look into [this](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs)